# Как посмотреть команду компиляции которую выполняет Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Где можно посмотреть команду которую VS (14) выполняет при сборке проекта ?

Answer (score 2):

Это то, что вы хотите?

Для компилятора:

Меню Проект->Свойства->С/С++->Командная строка

Ну и для компоновщике -

Меню Проект->Свойства->Компоновщик->Командная строка

Answer (score 0):

На вкладке Tools → Options → Build and Run доступны настройки детализации сообщений MSBuild при сборке. По-умолчанию там выставлена минимальная детализации, но при желании ее можно поднять до уровня "Detailed" или выше, тогда будут выводиться и выполняемые команды.